# Adding strong emphasis to an img tag. Semantics

Tags: xhtml, accessibility, semantics, web-standards

I'm actually coding a website and a doubt came to me. I have a list of images (it's an artist portfolio, so it should be images), some of which have a "Featured" badge. Is it semantically correct to wrap the img into a strong tag instead of using a class="featured"? Will it add strong emphasis to the image?

Reading the W3C spec., it refers strong and em as text-level semantics, but I'm not sure what happens with media like img.

Thank you so much.

Comment: My understanding is that most (all?) screenreaders ignore strong/em/b/i-type tags, and read all text at using the same voice, so don't rely on them; ensure that the ALT text is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's fine. You may already be doing this, but you need to make sure that the ALT text describes why the images has been emphasized. Eg alt="man with dog - featured"

Comment: +1 on ensuring that ALT text include this. If the badge is part of the image, the meaning of the badge needs to be part of the alt text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be perfectly acceptable to do this and preferable.

Comment: semantics is often about making judgement calls, In this case you are highlighting an image in markup if using a strong tag wheras using a stly mearley differentiates visually. You want this image marked differently in the HTML asfter all,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think the HTML 4 spec allows it. Question is, can you rely on what browser will do with it. I would not take my chances with that.

But at least, in many browsers you can attach formatting to

```
strong img {
    /* mark up for the featured image */
}
```

And this should then work for all browser that support it.

Comment: Oh, sure. In terms of styling there's no problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: BTW: if it's just emphasis you need, you can do `<em><img .. /></em>`. It is completely valid, just like `<strong>`

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use the strong tag on images, I am not sure why it would be preferable since it refers to 'emphasized' text only: an aural user agent may use different voices for emphasis, it would be pointless for images.

Why don't you just use a class?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly my doubt. Dunno if it really adds meaning to media content.

And regarding aural user agents, Bruce Lawson pointed this article to me: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/?p=41  Interesting...

Comment: Ah that's interesting, and a bit more confusing now, I would still go for classes, but that's me :P